# User info is not displaying from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I just want to display the username from database in my **UserHome.php** page. But it's displaying nothing. Here is the code below that I used to display the name.

**server.php :**

```
$host = "localhost";  
$user = "root";  
$password = '';  
$db_name = "hawkeye_portfolio";

$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);

     $name = "";

        if (isset($_POST['edit_user'])) {
         $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
         $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM edituser";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (count($results) == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $name = $n['name'];
      }
         
    }
```

**UserHome.php :**

```
ul class="address-text">
                                    <li><b>Name : </b></li>
                                    <li><?php echo $name; ?> </li>
                                </ul>
```

So here I want to display the name, But it's not displaying the name [imge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLLZV.png)

***Notice :***

I have also used this code

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
          $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
}


<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>
```

But these are not working too. Please someone help me.

Comment: Could you print_r($n) ? - see if you receive anything from the query... and maybe remove the : if (count($results) == 1 ) {... ?! perhaps you are getting more than one?

Comment: you haven't add where clause in select query . Hence it may return more than one result. That's why the name doesn't show. Try ` "SELECT * FROM edituser where name=$name and email = $email ` and then check.

Comment: Still it's not working, it's displaying nothig....@Rishni

Comment: I did as you say but it's showing a warning "Undefined variable $n in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\UserHome.php"........@Shlomtzion

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM edituser WHERE name='$name' AND email='$email'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) === 1) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
    {            
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        echo $_SESSION['name'];
    }

} else {
    // Show an error message
    // multiple results found
}
```

Comment: It's showing warning :  Undefined array key "name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\UserHome.php on line 72

Comment: This means your session doesn't have the $name. You must submit your form to the server.php first before outputting the data to the UserHome.php

Or Else, add the following line to the UserHome.php <?= $name ?? 'User Not Found' ?>

Comment: I did what you said, but it's showing nothing. no error, no output just blank.